# Portal 2 not downloading maps!

Tags: portal-2

Every time I try to download a map it gives me an error of "The map could not be downloaded". I have no screenshots, but I checked the development console and this is the code that tells the error more specificity:

```
--- Missing Vgui material vgui/hud/commands/gesture_smallwave
Unknown command "cl_thirdperson"
Unknown command "cl_thirdperson"
Unable to initialize DirectSoundCapture. You won't be able to speak to other     players.C_GameInstructor::ReadSaveData failed to read GI.lesson.Swap_Split_Screen_Control
An error occurred while attempting to download a file from the UGC server!
An error occurred while attempting to download a file from the UGC server!
An error occurred while attempting to download a file from the UGC server!
An error occurred while attempting to download a file from the UGC server!
```

Comment: I can only suggest it may be an issue with your Internet, anti-virus, or firewall. I have experienced issues regarding an aspect of a game that uses an Internet connection, not working. Even if the main function of the game does work. <br> my solution was to disable "web protection" in avg free.

Comment: I can say this probably isn't an issue with your configuration. I've had the same problem and it seems to be with 90% of maps but not all. I cannot download maps from the "recent" category, but normally can get them from "most popular". Also this issue is new.

Answer (score 1):

My short answer is to start trying to download again.

Whatever was behind this issue seems to have finally been fixed. I do not have a technical answer for you other than that this problem had been troubling me for a month or more. Though for the past couple of weeks I have been able to download maps without issue.

My assumption is that it was some problem on valve's server side, because I don't believe any patches came out between when this problem started and when I saw resolution to it.

PS:
If you had been making maps that no one could download because of this unpublish them, rename them and republish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm currently away from my gaming-pc, so I'll try tomorow

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue myself.

The reason it's happening is because when the game starts it downloads a list of all the chambers you ever played from the workshop, a bunch of files to steam/userdata/30752834/ugcmsgcache. This means this gets worse the more you play workshop chambers, and since there is no way to delete the play history from the workshop, I see no solution*(check later edit).

It's a small consolation but you can at least know when the ugc server connection is working properly by checking when the contents of the ugcmsgcache directory stop changing.

I submitted a ticket to steam support about this, but with no success so far.

* I later found out that there is a bit of a workaround, it isn't pretty, but works. You can activate the family sharing feature Steam has, then create a new account, add that account to the family sharing, and the next time you launch portal 2 on the new account, it won't download any ugcmsgcache files. When the file number increases too much on the new account, just make a new one. ^_^